# AWS lightsail Bitnami Wordpress Permissions 101

Tags: wordpress, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I'm new and find it a struggle to work with the permissions settings on AWS lightsail bitnami Wordpress.

1. I don't understand why do I have permissions restrictions despite login in as *bitnami* root user?
2. I use Cyberduck and login as *bitnami* with SSH key and yet I don't have permissions to delete files/folders.
3. Is there a cheatsheet to quickly set the permissions for Wordpress development purpose (for instance, write permissions to folders and files like *wp-content, wp-includes*, *php.ini, .htaccess, wp-config.php,* ..etc and to be able to delete, edit via sftp)and reset it once everything is completed?
4. I'm also confused with the directory structure. what is the difference between these two directory structures `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/` and `/home/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs`? They seem to sync with each other. Which is the right directory to use or either is fine?

I'm not sure if this is the right community to ask, if not please kindly direct me to the right community.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Bitnami Engineer here,

We configure the permissions of the WordPress' files by setting `bitnami` as the user owner and `daemon` as group owner of the files. However, if you make changes to the application using the web interface (install plugins or themes), those new files are owned by daemon:daemon (the Apache and PHP-FPM services use that user and group so they generate the files using those permissions configuration). In that case, you can run the following commands to be able to edit those files using the bitnami user

```
sudo chown -R /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs
sudo find /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
sudo find /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
sudo chmod 640 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php
```

You can learn more about this here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLGgVZHi3XQNn4x0DU7Qj1r_inej3xEUda&v=nKfle7O0vN8&feature=emb_title

Answer (score 0):

From Jota Martos answer I used the commands but with different paths for bitnami at lightsail (update in 2022 ) are

```
/opt/bitnami/wordpress/

/bitnami/wordpress
```

I advise doing the commands twice with every path

Answer (score 0):

I've just used the above code to update my file permission configuration and the website is blank now.

Which could be the issue? Do you have a clue of I can restore the website?